# How to scramble a word, keeping first and last characters the same?

Tags: algorithms, javascript, efficiency, strings

I have a task, which is to scramble a single word, whose size is greater than 3 letters.

The scrambled word must not be equal to the original, and the first and last letters of the word must remain the same.

For example, the word `stack`, could give the one of the following results:

- satck
- scatk
- stcak
- sactk
- etc

While words like `is` or `hey` for example, would remain unchanged for being too small.

My attempt to do this can be seen below. I have a JavaScript function that received a word to scramble, and then I choose random indexes within a certain limit to create a new scrambled word and return it. If the index I have chosen was already picked, then I try again hoping for a new result.

```
/**
 * Returns a scrambled word with the first and last letters unchanged
 * that is NOT EQUAL to the given parameter 'word', provided it has 
 * more than three characters.
 */
function scrambleWord(word){

  if(word.length <= 3)
    return word;

  var selectedIndexes, randomCharIndex, scrambledWord = word;

  while(word === scrambledWord){
    selectedIndexes = [], randomCharIndex, scrambledWord = '';
    scrambledWord += word[0];
    for(var j = 0; j < word.length-2; j++){

      //select random char index making sure it is not repeated
      randomCharIndex = getRandomInt(1, word.length-2);
      while(selectedIndexes.indexOf(randomCharIndex) > -1 && selectedIndexes.length != word.length-2){
        randomCharIndex = getRandomInt(1, word.length-2);
      }

      scrambledWord += word[randomCharIndex];
      selectedIndexes.push(randomCharIndex);
    }
    scrambledWord += word[word.length-1];
  }
  return scrambledWord;
}

/**
 * Returns a random integer between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive)
 * Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
 * See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1527820/1337392
 */
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

The problem with this approach, is that it is too slow. I fail the tests because I exceed the time limit of 6 seconds, so I definitely need to improve this solution, but I can't see where I can do it.

From an algorithm perspective, what is the most efficient way that uses the least amount of worst case operations that I can approach this problem?

Comment: Do you have to produce random results, or could you consistently scramble `stack` as `sactk`?

Comment: The results must be random :D

Comment: Are you sure that this code works, and that the only problem with it is that it is too slow?

Comment: And what happens with words like "moot" ?

Comment: @Alternatex I had no idea that existed! I simply follow this answer on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-programmers-se

Comment: @MikeNakis good point. In this case, my code loops indefinitely, which is a bug I had not realized ! I need a function fix this!

Comment: @MikeNakis The full question is a Kata from codewars. You can see it here: http://www.codewars.com/kata/564e48ebaaad20181e000024/train/javascript

Comment: I don't want to have to sign up with codewars.com to see the question.

Comment: I suppose the real trick is to see if and how you deal with the "moot" case, or if nothing else, if you ask how to deal with that case to show that you consider such things.

Comment: @Neil if I get a word like "moot", i just return it. Turns out there was yet another exception, thanks guys!

Comment: Rather than editing what you did back into your question, it would be appropriate to answer your own question.  See [Can I answer my own question?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Comment: @DanPichelman Well, yes but, I already picked an answer! It would be unfair for the people that helped me to not get the credit for doing it!

Comment: this question is discussed [at MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271620/165773) and [at Programmers meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7817/31260)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the following lines; treating the string as a character array:

- Handle strings that are 3 or fewer characters, or all the middle characters are the same
- Create a sublist of the letters excluding the first and last
- [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) the middle letters until they don't match the original (this can be done in O(n) time)
- Reattach the first and last letter

A faster shuffle can be used, if it is allowed to be less random (e.g. ln(n) random swaps).  In the extreme case this can be reduced to [Mike Nakis' answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/304837/54700)

Comment: In the case of "moot", you wind up in an endless loop this way.

Comment: True. I've also not handled the case where the string is <=3

Answer (score 2):

1. Let `n` be `word.length - 3`. (Yes, '3'.)
2. Issue a random index `i` in the range `0`...`n`.
3. Swap the letters at `word[1 + n]` and `word[1 + n + 1]`.

you are done.

If there is a possibility that the word may contain two identical letters, then whoever gave you this assignment must first answer what happens with words like "moot".  Assuming that they will say "moot" stays same, but "schmoot" must become something other than "schmoot", then:

1.b Check if all letters except first and last are same.  If they are, you are done.

2.b Keep repeating step 2 until the letters at `word[1 + n]` and `word[1 + n + 1]` are different.

Comment: The example could equally be "mooot".  It isn't sufficient to check if they're just 4-letter words.

Comment: @Neil You are right.  I believe I have fixed it now.

Comment: It certainly works, and I give you props for the approach that is potentially O(1).